# Django custom save model admin page

Tags: python, django, overriding

When overriding the django save_model method, how do I extract the key value.
Let's say the admin page has a input for the key "name". How do I extract that value in the method:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    //request.name?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a field by making use of `form.cleaned_data`, like this:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    # ...
```